# Installed bitcoin-qt via snap, now can't find wallet folder

Tags: 20.04, bitcoin

I'm trying to import in a old wallet to this new core.  I tried looking in the `~/bitcoin/` and it says the directory doesn't exist.  I also checked all the directories in `~/snap/bitcoin-core/` but see no wallet.dat files.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it via

```
find / -name wallet.dat -print 2>/dev/null
```